# CodeIgniter Number Sequence

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm really new to codeigniter (and stackoverflow as you can see XD) as per my course so far

I'm kind of slumped as I can't figure out what is wrong with my code since I'm constantly getting a syntax error.

```
<?php
    class PrintSequence extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function MarioFlagPole($num)
        {   
            parent::MarioFlagPole();
            $j = 1;
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++)
            {
                $count = 1;
                while($count <= $i+1) 
                {
                    echo $j;
                    $j++;
                    $count++;
                }
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
        MarioFlagPole(5);
    }
    
?>
```

Comment: What is the goal of this code? On which line do you think the issue is?

Comment: `MarioFlagPole(5)` is outside of any function in a class. isn't that thing illegal? you should call `MarioFlagPole` somewhere else (e.g. in route entry point).

Comment: You can't put a random command in the middle of a class definition, outside a function. It's like no-mans-land...that code cannot be executable. You neglected to mention the error you're getting or the line which throws it, but that seems to be the likely candidate. I'm assuming you haven't quite got the hang of classes and functions yet,.

Comment: Also, since it's a class method it should be `$this->MarioFlagPole(...)`